# Mute HTML 5 video & random video load

Tags: html, audio, video, random, mute

Three part question...

I'm using http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/index.html for HTML 5 video background on my site. Works perfectly! However I have some additional functions I want to add on but not quite sure how to pull it off.

1_ I would like to add a button to mute/unmute audio. I'm not that great at jquery so what I'm looking for is what I need to add to the existing code to make it happen and what I need to put in the place where I want the actual button to go. I'm guessing I need to add some mute option to...

```
    $('.bg').videoBG({
    position:"fixed",
    zIndex:0,
    mp4:'_video/ClimbBG.mp4',
    ogv:'_video/ClimbBG.ogv',
    webm:'_video/ClimbBG.webm',
    poster:'_images/ClimbBG.jpg',
    opacity:1,
    fullscreen:true,

});
```

Then some function/code in the spot I want the button to be?

2_ I would like to have a different random video load each time the site is loaded. Maybe even have a new video play after the first one is finished? 
Example...This site loads a different video when the page is refreshed (  cabin-time.com  )

3_ Not super important but I've noticed a lot of people who use video backgrounds have little dots in the video (cabin-time.con is one example). I'm guessing this is to reduce file size? Most likely done in Final Cut? How do I add this into my video and does it really reduce file size?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, VideoBG does not support mute, so you can't just 'add mute option' to it, you'll need to make it yourself.

Here are some points to get you started, edit the videoBG.js, to add a 'muted' attribute ( http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/jquery.videoBG.js )

```
......
// video element
    var $video = $('<video/>');
    $video.css('position','absolute')
        .css('z-index',options.zIndex)
        .attr('poster',options.poster)
        .attr('muted',options.muted)
        .css('top',0)
        .css('left',0)
        .css('min-width','100%')
        .css('min-height','100%');
 .......
 // these are the defaults
$.fn.videoBG.defaults = {
        mp4:'',
        ogv:'',
        webm:'',
        poster:'',
        autoplay:true,
        loop:5,
        sclae:false,
        position:"absolute",
        opacity:1,
        textReplacement:false,
        zIndex:0,
        width:0,
        height:0,
        muted:false
```

Now you can add `muted:true` to your properties

Comment: I added all the above^ code. Still not working. I'm really new to .js. When you say I'll need to make it myself are you saying I'll have to write out some js function that calls on the muted attribute?

Comment: If you want to avoid coding, try to add 'controls', just like you added 'muted', see if this is enough. Otherwise, you'll need to write js (Add a button, add an 'on_click' handler to it, make the handler change the video settings, etc.)  basically, more than a Stackoverflow question - you'll need to learn at least some js.